# Fix case sensitive url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Based on the sample original link:
https://www.example.com/filename.html

How to make the it still work even the url has uppercase characters using .htaccess?
Ex.: HTTPS://www.example.com/Filename.html

Everytime I used rewrite map it shows forbidden error and I don't know how to fix it. I already try different code from any website and sources and I am still struggling to fix it.